# Dynamically create Hive external table with Avro schema on Parquet Data

Tags: hive, avro, parquet

I'm trying to dynamically (without listing column names and types in Hive DDL) create a Hive external table on parquet data files. I have the Avro schema of underlying parquet file.

My try is to use below DDL:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'hdfs://myParquetFilesPath'
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='http://myHost/myAvroSchema.avsc');
```

My Hive table is successfully created with the right schema, but when I try to read the data :

```
SELECT * FROM parquet_test;
```

I get the following error :

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerdeException: Expecting a AvroGenericRecordWritable
```

Is there a way to successfully create and read Parquet files, without mentioning columns name and types list in DDL?

Comment: If the underlying data is in parquet format, I believe it is not possible to read using avro schema. It is more like reading french book with english dictionary in hand.

Comment: I'm only using AvroSerDe for schema inference...

Comment: Above error(Expecting a AvroGenericRecordWritable) indicates you are trying to read parquet format record with AvroSerde. ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' tells hive to use AvroSerde to decode the data, but data is not in avro format.

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to find an alternative solution, maybe I should generate a Hive query from an Avro schema. But I'm surprised that there is not a simpler solution.

Comment: I haven't tested but try this CREATE TABLE avro_test
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS AVRO
TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='http://myHost/myAvroSchema.avsc');

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test
LIKE avro_test
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 'hdfs://myParquetFilesPath';

Comment: You have to use avro tools to convert the avro schema into a hive schema. Hive abstracts the parquet details. See https://developer.ibm.com/hadoop/blog/2015/11/10/use-parquet-tools-avro-tools-iop-4-1/ for avro tools.

Comment: Ram, your idea is great ! I just tried it and now I got :

java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable

Comment: Roberto, thanks for a lot for your pointer. I'm trying to find out how I can convert a Avro schema into a Hive schema. Sounds like I can't do it directly, I should write some code for it, right ?

Comment: I have tested it works..! From the error message I think you avro schema file is messed up.. Try using parquet tools to regenerate the avro schema from parquet file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Hive table to read parquet files from parquet/avro schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202743/create-hive-table-to-read-parquet-files-from-parquet-avro-schema)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below query works:

```
CREATE TABLE avro_test ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' STORED AS AVRO TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='myHost/myAvroSchema.avsc'); 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test LIKE avro_test STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'hdfs://myParquetFilesPath';
```

Comment: I'm running Hive 1.1.0 and that doesn't work for me. I get `java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable`

Comment: The error mesage indicates that a particular column is in text format in parquet file and in your avro schema it is defined as int. Hence the error. Change your avro schema of that particular column to String and retry.

Comment: I think my problem came from different and incompatible schemas. It's working fine now. Thank you !

Comment: Another solution is to create my own SerDe : what I **only** need from `AvroSerDe` is schema inference from an avro schema. So, I have to create a class that extends `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe` and override method `public boolean shouldStoreFieldsInMetastore(Map<String, String> tableParams)` using an `org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerde` object. This seems easy to write with Hive 1.2.0.

Comment: I am geeting FAILED: ParseException line 1:55 missing EOF at 'STORED' near avro_test . Hive version -0.14. Runs well on hive 1.2

Comment: do you know how to add a column using the avro.schema.literal to a table created in this fashion?