# Create Hive table to read parquet files from parquet/avro schema

Tags: hive, avro, parquet

We are looking for a solution in order to create an external hive table to read data from parquet files according to a parquet/avro schema.

in other way, how to generate a hive table from a parquet/avro schema ?

thanks :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try below using avro schema:

```
CREATE TABLE avro_test ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' STORED AS AVRO TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='myHost/myAvroSchema.avsc'); 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test LIKE avro_test STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'hdfs://myParquetFilesPath';
```

Same query is asked in [Dynamically create Hive external table with Avro schema on Parquet Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181844/dynamically-create-hive-external-table-with-avro-schema-on-parquet-data)

Comment: Can I create table from parquet file directly ? Or how to get Avro schema from specific parquet file ?

Comment: @GaryGauh for your second question here's my answer . Using parquet tools you can extract Avro schema of the particular parquet file. Please refer this link for more details : http://kitesdk.org/docs/0.17.1/labs/4-using-parquet-tools-solution.html

Comment: It worked for me but can i use parquet schema (`org.apache.parquet.schema.MessageType`) to create tables?