# How to read parquet thrift file from hive?

Tags: hive, thrift, parquet

I have created hive external table on a file written inparquet using thrift schema.  Which Serde do we need to pass to read this file?

Comment: IMHO your best option is to **develop** that SerDe yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Hive table to read parquet files from parquet/avro schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202743/create-hive-table-to-read-parquet-files-from-parquet-avro-schema)