# Athena create table from parquet schema

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hive, presto, amazon-athena

Is there a way to create a table in Amazon Athena directly from parquet file based on avro schema? The schema is encoded into the file so its seems stupid that I need to actually create the DDL myself.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202743/create-hive-table-to-read-parquet-files-from-parquet-avro-schema) and also another [duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181844/dynamically-create-hive-external-table-with-avro-schema-on-parquet-data)

but they are related directly to Hive, it wont work for Athena.
Ideally I am looking for a way to do it programmatically without the need to define it at the console.

Comment: It would be more productive to try it (or at least read the documentation - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/creating-tables.html) than to decide that it won't work.

Comment: read and tried, Athena only support CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE, the suggested solution is based on CREATE TABLE for the avro schema and only than create external one for the parquet

Comment: So create an external table. Why should it matter?

Comment: I don't know thats exactly the reason I post this question.. Tried to change it to an external table but it failed to create it with this kind of syntax. If you have a working an example on Athena you are more than welcome to share :)

Comment: Unfortunately I have access to Presto but not to Athena, otherwise I would supply an answer way before... :-) Can you share the error you got when you tried using external table?

Answer (score 8):

This is now more-or-less possible using [AWS Glue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/what-is-glue.html). Glue can crawl a bunch of different data sources, including [Parquet files on S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-classifier.html). Discovered tables are added to the Glue data catalog and queryable from Athena. Depending on your needs, you could schedule a Glue crawler to run periodically, or you could define and run a crawler using the Glue API.

If you have many separate hunks of data that share a schema, you can also use a [partitioned table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partitions.html) to reduce the overhead of making new loads available to Athena. For example, I have some daily dumps that load into tables partitioned by date. As long as the schema doesn't change, all you then need to do is `MSCK REPAIR TABLE`.

Comment: Glue crawls the data source. Want create table only. Athena does not need glue just schema copy/paste etc which is already defined in the parquet. Product managers at all?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem to be possible with Athena as `avro.schema.url` is not a supported property.

`table property 'avro.schema.url' is not supported. (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException...)`

You can use `avro.schema.literal` (you would have to copy the avro json schema to the query) but I still experienced problems querying the data afterwards.

Strange errors like:
`SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: SELECT * not allowed in queries without FROM clause`

Comment: The "strange error" you mentioned seems to be a bug in presto: https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/8654