# Converting Parquet to CSV

Tags: csv, hdfs, parquet

I have parquet files in my hdfs. I want to convert these parquet files into csv format & copy to local.
I tried this:

```
hadoop fs -text /user/Current_Data/partitioned_key=MEDIA/000000_0  > /home/oozie-coordinator-workflows/quality_report/media.csv

hadoop fs -copyToLocal /user/Current_Data/partitioned_key=MEDIA/000000_0 /home/oozie-coordinator-workflows/quality_report/media1.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing will not work, you are just reading and writing the parquet data not converting.

You can do it with spark or hive/impala, below is the explanation in spark.

**SPARK:**

Read the parquet files:

`df = spark.read.parquet("/user/Current_Data/partitioned_key=MEDIA/")`

**Write it to HDFS:**

```
df.write.csv("home/oozie-coordinator-workflows/quality_report/media1.csv")
```

Check out out more on the above [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader.parquet).

**HIVE :**

```
CREATE TABLE test ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe' STORED AS AVRO TBLPROPERTIES ('avro.schema.url'='myHost/myAvroSchema.avsc'); 

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE parquet_test LIKE test STORED AS PARQUET LOCATION 'hdfs:///user/Current_Data/partitioned_key=MEDIA/';
```

After you have the table you can create a CSV file through beeline/hive with the below command.

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://[databaseaddress]' --outputformat=csv2 -e "select * from parquet_test" > /local/path/toTheFile.csv
```

Check the below two links for more explanation.

[Dynamically create Hive external table with Avro schema on Parquet Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34181844/dynamically-create-hive-external-table-with-avro-schema-on-parquet-data)

[Export as csv in beeline hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39577036/export-as-csv-in-beeline-hive)

Comment: Your first link is no longer available.